# Можно ли получить путь к папке используя input?

Tags: php

Можно ли получить путь к папке используя `<input type="file">` ?
Нажимаю кнопку и выбираю папку которая мне нужна для копирования. Или это как то по другому делается?

Comment: такая возможность была кажется только через flash (Загрузка фото вконтакте была реализована так), js тоже не пускает, только дает выбранный файл/файлы

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. По причинам безопасности браузеры не дают такую возможность.
Выбирать можно только файлы или группу файлов.